# Can I power this portable TV with batteries?

Tags: power-supply, portable

(I'm really new to electronics).

My idea is to take the integrated power supply out and connect the wires to a buck converter, then wire some batteries. Could this possibly work? Basically I want this "portable" Roadstar TV-400n that runs from mains to actually be portable.

Comment: You could plug the TV into mains and measure the DC-Voltages the internal PSUP provides. Then also measure the currents. After this, there should be no issue to just supply it from Bat->DC/DC->PCB. But also be aware of eventual digital communications with the PSUP (Status, Data, PowerGood, etc.) and Rail-Sequencing (12V before 5V - delay of x ms for eample). So by using a multimeter, a scope and some time this is doable.

When dealing with mains: Never touch the shiny. And also: There can be !HIGH! Dc-Voltages present, even if mains are disconnected!!

Comment: Google is telling me this is a CRT TV from the year 1990. Is that right? The batteries will last much longer with a more modern device - just think of a smartphone watching Youtube.

Comment: That's right, but smartphone is boring

Comment: I know that CRTs need to be discharged, I'm gonna research more on that, but information varies. One says that a screwdriver with a wire connected to mains ground is enough, other says he got shocked, lost consciousness and doesn't feel his arm anymore...

Comment: I personally, after +10 years in hobby electronics, would not feel confident hacking around in this thing. Think twice is my advice.

Comment: You can make a battery powered AC inverter.

Comment: Umm... Didn't the terrestrial TV frequency spectrum get given to the cell phone companies or get switched to digital (not analog anymore) when everybody went HD ???    i.e. what exactly do you expect to be watching besides "flight of the bumblebees"

Comment: CRT's don't need discharging... it's the monster capacitors that need discharging.   And yes, if you touch the wrong thing while it's charged, it'll knock you into next week.  Think 2000V or thereabouts

Comment: @KyleB In many televisions the picture tube actually is a big capacitor, they have a conductive coating on the outside as well as the aquadag coating in the inside, which form the plates of a capacitor to filter the anode supply. So the tube can carry a rather high voltage and touching the anode connection and the outside of the tube at the same time will not be a pleasant experience.

Answer (score 1):

From [radiomuseum](https://www.radiomuseum.org/r/roadstar_tv_400n.html) I find this:

> Power type and voltage Line / Storage batteries (perhaps also
> batteries) / 220/ 12 Volt

so perhaps it will already operate off of batteries.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=em1O7rrhs7A) shows a 12 V connector on the rear and the word *charge*, so maybe it has internal rechargable batteries.

Comment: Interesting! There really seems to be at least an option to have 12 V and battery internally!

Comment: I don't see any lids, don't know if it was normal in the 90s to put batteries actually inside the TV.  Also can't see any batteries on the blueprint, but as I said, I'm new to this so maybe you could spot them: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11_N7f2zeOCyh2meMMW3DTD8f-bjtLcAr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It was common at one time to make portables that would run off either 220V (or 120V) or a 12V car battery.

Comment: the schematic diagram shows that the 12 V jack is for connecting an external battery pack ... there is a circuit for charging the battery ... an external 12 V power supply could also be used if the charging switch is turned off

Comment: Well that is very convenient then! @Kofa can just buy the appropriate matching plug (these are still manufactured, not obsolete at all) and hook up a 12V battery of his/her choice. I am confused how the voltage regulator circuit works, but it looks like there is one, so I would guess this is probably designed to run from lead acid battery (10-14 volts depending how much it's charged) and doesn't need a precise 12V - that also makes sense for why there's a charge switch which feeds some power from the mains plug into the battery.

Comment: If you use a lithium battery instead of lead-acid, then don't use the charge switch to charge the battery. Lead-acid batteries are quite resilient; lithium batteries aren't, and could explode if you don't use the proper charging system. (The switch is harmless when the mains power is not connected, and it's also harmless when the TV is taking power from the battery)

Comment: Thank you! That's the answer. However, i don't know how to mark comments as solutions...